# How to wait multiple nested async calls by using of RxJava-Android?

Tags: android, asynchronous, rx-java

I'm new to RxJava, here's my case,

1. send request A and will get `List<A>` back
2. for each A, send request AA and will get AA back, bind A and AA then
3. there is B & BB with similar logic
4. do something only after all requests complete

Example:

```
request(url1, callback(List<A> listA) {
    for (A a : listA) {
        request(url2, callback(AA aa) {
            a.set(aa);
        }
    }
}
```

A and B are independent

How to structure the code? I also used Retrofit as network client.

Comment: Handlers and a progress integer to control if you reach the end of the logic or not.

Comment: @Oliveira, yes, handler is one solution, but I want to know if RxJava could offer a better and simple solution

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "bind A and AA"? So you have one request that yields a List of As, and then for each A there will be exactly one AA? Also, do you still need the As when you have the AAs? What are you going to do with the AAs - is there one action for each or a combined action for all AAs together?

Comment: @david.mihola, there is one AA for every A, 1-1 map. I can't get both A & AA in one request because of limit of server. The "bind A and AA" is the action after AA retrieved, sth like A.set(AA)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

OK, I think this should solve the first part of your problem:

Notice that the second call to `flatMap` is given 2 arguments - there is a version of `flatMap` that not only produces an Observable for each input item but that also take a second function which in turn will combine each item from the resulting Observable with the corresponding input item.

Have a look at the third graphic under this heading to get an intuitive understanding:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Transforming-Observables#flatmap-concatmap-and-flatmapiterable

```
Observable<A> obeservableOfAs = retrofitClient.getListOfAs()
.flatMap(new Func1<List<A>, Observable<A>>() {

    @Override
    public Observable<A> call(List<A> listOfAs) {
        return Observable.from(listOfAs);
    }

)}
.flatMap(new Func1<A, Observable<AA>>() {

    @Override
    public Observable<AA> call(A someA) {
        return retrofitClient.getTheAaForMyA(someA);
    }

},
new Func2<A, AA, A>() {

    @Override
    public A call(A someA, AA theAaforMyA) {
        return someA.set(theAaforMyA);
    }

})
...
```

From here on I am still not sure how you want to continue: Are you ready to just subscribe to the resulting Observable of As? That way you could handle each of the As (`onNext`) or just wait until all are done (`onCompleted`).

**ADDENDUM:** To collect all Items into a single List at the end, that is turn your `Observable<A>` into an `Observable<List<A>>` use `toList()`.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Mathematical-and-Aggregate-Operators#tolist

So you have:

```
Observable<List<A>> observableOfListOfAs = observableOfAs.toList();
```

If you need more fine grained control over the construction of your list, you can also use `reduce`.

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Mathematical-and-Aggregate-Operators#reduce

For the Bs, simply duplicate the whole flow you used for the As.

You can then use `zip` to wait for both flows to complete:

```
Observable.zip(
    observableOfListOfAs,
    observableOfListOfBs,
    new Func2<List<A>, List<B>, MyPairOfLists>() {

        @Override
        public MyPairOfLists call(List<A> as, List<B> bs) {
            return new MyPairOfLists(as, bs);
        }
    }
)
.subscribe(new Subscriber<MyPairOfLists>() {

    // onError() and onCompleted() are omitted here

    @Override
    public void onNext(MyPairOfLists pair) {
        // now both the as and the bs are ready to use:

        List<A> as = pair.getAs();
        List<B> bs = pair.getBs();

        // do something here!
    }
});
```

I suppose you can guess the definition of `MyPairOfLists`.

Comment: Thanks, Func2 for flatmap looks great! At the end, I would require collection A, I think there will be a merge? How's B part then?

Comment: So you need to wait until all As have their AA and then collect them into a list? I think the Bs should work just like the As? And there is a final action that should be executed when both the List<A> and the List<B> are ready?

Comment: thanks for your patient explanation, now everything worked! RxJava did make code clean and simple!

Comment: @david.mihola I'm making a list of async network request using rxjava-async,not use `Retrofit`,the exception says I have used it in main thread,but I've subscribeOn new thread.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the zip is emitting the elements in pairs. Instead of zip what operator can I use to get notified at the end of both lists? I have two lists of requests (with different sizes), and just want to execute some code at the end.