# Combining API responses in RxJava where one of the APIs returns a list

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm trying to use RxJava to combine the responses from two API calls. The scenario is the following: The first API call returns a list of User objects. Each User object contain a postcode, but they do not contain a city name. To get the city name a second API is called, with the parameter being the postcode.

Ideally I want to modify the original list of User objects, and add the city name after it has been fetched in the second API call, but I'm stuck at figuring out how to do it.

Comment: Look at my answer here, which describes a solution to something similiar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26376704/763935 The main point is that there is another version of `flatMap` that takes combines the input and output (so to speak) to produce a new output.

Answer (score 2):

This seems like a pretty straightforward observable:

Dummy API for users:

```
public static List<String> getUsers() {
    return new ArrayList<String>() {
        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        {
            add("Anakin");
            add("Darth");
        }
    };
}
```

Dummy API for city:

```
public static String getCity(String name) {
    // dummy ..
    return "Mos Espa";
}
```

Merging together:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Observable.from(getUsers()).flatMap(
        // we have the user
        user -> Observable.just(getCity(user)).map(
            // we have the city
            city -> user + " from " + city)) // do stuff with user + city
        .subscribe(result -> System.out.println(result));
}
```

Comment: The problem I'm ultimately trying to solve is to end up with a list of users in `subscribe(..)`, where the only difference from the original list of users is that city name is added to the user. Is there a good way to achieve this? I guess one option is to add the users to a new list in `subscribe(..)`, but are there better ways?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my understanding of your question. You have 2 API calls...

```
public Observable<List<User>> getUsers();
public Observable<String> getCityName(String postalCode);
```

And you want to set each user's city name based on the call to `getCityName`. You can convert the List into an observable stream by flatMapping it into an `Observable` from an `Iterable`. Here is one way to do that.

```
Observable<User> usersWithCity = getUsers()
        .flatMap(new Func1<List<User>, Observable<User>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<User> call(List<User> users) {
                return Observable.from(users);
            }})
        .flatMap(new Func1<User, Observable<User>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<User> call(User user) {
                return getCityName(user.getPostalCode())
                        .doOnNext(new Action1<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void call(String t) {
                                user.setCityName(t);
                            }
                        })
                        .map(new Func1<String, User>() {
                            @Override
                            public User call(String cityName) {
                                return user;
                            }
                        });
            }
});
```

Note that this makes the assumption that there will only ever be one cityName for each postalCode.

Comment: The difference is that I have `Observable<List<User>`

Comment: Thanks for the correction! I have updated my answer to convert from a list into an observable of users.