# RxJava : update result of call with results of subsequent calls

Tags: java, android, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-android

I have a 2 calls:

1. `getItems()` - that returns a `List<Item>`, also `Item` has `id` field
2. `getParam(id)` - that returns `Param`

I need to make `getItems()` and then `getParam(id)` for every `Item` in `List` and then need to update every `Item` with received `Param`

My question is:

How can I make this using RxJava?

```
            api.getItems()
                    .flatMapIterable(new Func1<List<Item>, Iterable<Item>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Iterable<Item> call(List<Item> items) {
                            return items;
                        }
                    })
                    .flatMap(new Func1<Item, Observable<?>>() {
                        @Override
                        public Observable<?> call(Item item) {
                            return api.getParam(item.id)
                        }
                    }),

                    ...

                    .subscribe(...);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this helps for merging the results of both your calls: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356852/how-to-wait-mulitple-nested-async-calls-by-using-of-rxjava-android/26376704#26376704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the two-parameter `flatMap`; the second parameter is a `Func2` that will receive both the original item and each result from the first parameter's call.