# how to write nested network request use rxjava + retrofit2

Tags: android, rx-java, retrofit2

I am using Rxjava and Retrofit2.0 in my project, it looks like this:

```
Observable<List<A>>  getAFromServer();
Observable<List<B>>  getBFromServer(@Body A.a);
```

If I don't use reactive way, it will be like this:

```
List<A> listA = getAFromServer();
foreach(A a: listA){
        getBFromServer(a.a)
}
```

So, my question is how to use Rxjava to achieve this and what operator to use?

Comment: see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356852/how-to-wait-mulitple-nested-async-calls-by-using-of-rxjava-android

Comment: Fixed language related things and spaces.

Answer (score 8):

**With Rx you can finally stop thinking about "nesting" network requests.**

If you think about it, you never really wanted to "nest" network requests, right? That was only how the code ended up looking because you had only `AsyncTask`s or other callbacks at your disposal.

With Rx you can finally write code that in its structure resembles what you actually want to, which is *chain network requests*: *First* do one thing, *then* do another.

```
getAFromServer()
    .flatMap(new Func1<List<A>, Observable<A>>() {       
        @Override
        public Observable<A> call(List<A> list) {
            // the first flatMap is just a trick to "flatten" the Observable
            return Observable.from(list);
        }
    })
    .flatMap(new Func1<A, Observable<B>>() {
        @Override
        public Observable<A> call(A someA) {
            return getBFromServer(someA.a);
        }

    })
    .subscribe(...);
```