# sequential multiple api calls in RxJava , Retrofit - order gets mixed up

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have a list of data which again contains , 2 string URL, which again should place 2 api calls to fetch result and add those data to the main list  and then display in the listview .

Here i am able to obtain the list with right data but the order gets mismatched . Is that like the first completed result gets added to my ArrayList or something . Please help .

Here is my code below :

```
void handleOrdersResponse(@NonNull List<OrderRowViewModel> response) {
    for (int i = 0; i < response.size(); i++) {
        String fulfillmentUrl = response.get(i).mFulFillmentMethodUrl.get();
        String paymentUrl = response.get(i).mPaymentMethodUrl.get();
        OrderRowViewModel response1 = response.get(i);
        subscribe(Observable.zip(getFulFillment(fulfillmentUrl), getPayment(paymentUrl), Pair::new)
                .compose(ObservableTransformers.getInstance().networkOperation())
                .doOnSubscribe(() -> {

                })

                .subscribe(pair -> {
                            response1.setOrderFulFilemntname(pair.first.state(), pair.first.state());
                            response1.setPaymnetType(response1.mPaymentTitle.get(), pair.second.methodData().methodName());
                            mModels.add(response1);

                            mFilteredConversations.add(response1);

                            if (mFilteredConversations.size() == response.size() && mModels.size() == response.size()) {
                                mAdapter.refresh();
                            }
                        },
                        throwable -> mEventBus.post(new BaseActivity.ShowSnackbarEvent(R.string.failure_updating_store))));
    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to call API in sequential order than you should use flatMap

Comment: what is the subscribe call/method?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356852/how-to-wait-mulitple-nested-async-calls-by-using-of-rxjava-android